# django sudo runserver kicking up an error

Tags: django

When I try to run `sudo ./manage.py runserver`, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./manage.py", line 9, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 429, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 379, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 252, in fetch_command
    app_name = get_commands()[subcommand]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 101, in get_commands
    apps = settings.INSTALLED_APPS
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 276, in __getattr__
    self._setup()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 42, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 139, in __init__
    logging_config_func(self.LOGGING)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/config.py", line 776, in dictConfig
    dictConfigClass(config).configure()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/config.py", line 562, in configure
    'filter %r: %s' % (name, e))
ValueError: Unable to configure filter 'require_debug_false': Cannot resolve 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugFalse': No module named RequireDebugFalse
```

Running `./manage.py runserver` works perfectly fine.

Doing a bit of digging around, I found that this might be related to a Django1.3 bug? However, I'm in a virtualenv running Django 1.4 pre-alpha.

The reason why I need the sudo command is because I'm trying to runserver from port 80 which requires sudo.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

When you run `manage.py` with `sudo` it does not use activated virtual env. Most probably, you have another version of django installed outside virtualenv.

You can run using the python executable from virtualenv, ie:

```
$ sudo /home/USER/.virtualenvs/YOUR_PROJECT/bin/python manage.py runserver
```

You can get python executable path from virtualenv:

```
$ which python
```

Comment: Exactly as bmihelac says. Super9, you can see in your stack trace that you're not executing Django from your virtual env. You're executing the Django that's in your system-wide path. RequireDebugFalse is probably only available in your 1.4 virtualenv.